# Pandas: Apply a function to exploded values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have the following dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [8, [10, 11, 12, 13], [6, 7, 8, 9]]], columns=list("abc"))`

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [2] | [3] |
| 8 | [10,11,12,13] | [6,7,8,9] |

Columns b and c can consist of 1 to n elements, but in a row they will always have the same number of elements.

I am looking for a way to explode the columns b and c, while applying a function to the whole row, here for example in order to divide the column a by the number of elements in b and c (I know this is a stupid example as this would be easily solvable by first dividing, then exploding. The real use case is a bit more complicated but of no importance here.)
So the result would look something like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 10 | 6 |
| 2 | 11 | 7 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 |
| 2 | 13 | 9 |

I tried using the apply-method like in the following snippet, but this only produced garbage and does not work, when the number of elements in the list does not fit the number of columns:

```
def fun(row):
    if isinstance(row.c, list):
        result = [[row.a, row.b, c] for c in row.c]
        return result
    return row
            

df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Panda's explode explode function also doesn't really fit here for me, because afterwards there is no chance of telling anymore, whether the rows were exploded or not.

Is there an easier way than to iterate through the data-frame, exploding the values and manually building up a new data-frame in the way I need it here?

Thank you already for your help.

Edit:

The real use case is basically a mapping from b+c to a.
So I have another file that looks something like that:

| b | c | a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 6 | 1 |
| 11 | 7 | 1 |
| 12 | 8 | 2 |
| 13 | 9 | 4 |

So coming from this example, the result would actually be as follows:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 6 |
| 1 | 11 | 7 |
| 2 | 12 | 8 |
| 4 | 13 | 9 |

The problem is, that between this two files there is no 1:1 relation between those two files as it might seem here.

Comment: why don't you explain in a bit more details the real use-case?

Comment: @mozway I added a bit more information about the real use case.

Comment: can't you `merge`? `df.explode(['b', 'c']).drop(columns='a').merge(df2, on=['b', 'c'])`

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Panda's explode function also doesn't really fit here for me, *because afterwards there is no chance of telling anymore, whether the rows were exploded or not*.

This isn't true. Consider this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [8, [10, 11, 12, 13], [6, 7, 8, 9]]], columns=list("abc"))

# explode
df2 = df.explode(['b','c'])
```

As you can see from the print below, the result *also* explodes the index:

```
   a   b  c
0  1   2  3
1  8  10  6
1  8  11  7
1  8  12  8
1  8  13  9
```

So, we can use the index to track how many elements per row got exploded. Try this:

```
# reset index, add old index as column and create a Series with frequence 
# for old index; now populate 'a' with 'a' divided by this Series
df2.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df2['a'] = df2['a']/df2.loc[:,'index'].map(df2.loc[:,'index'].value_counts())

# drop the old index, now as column
df2.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
     a   b  c
0  1.0   2  3
1  2.0  10  6
2  2.0  11  7
3  2.0  12  8
4  2.0  13  9
```